# Метод preg_replace c числовым значением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Например, вот так - нужно заменить значение height в стилях элемента div. Если я сделаю вот так:

```
$height  = "100px";
$css = preg_replace('/(div{height:\s?).*(;})/', "$1$height$2",$css)
```

то ничего не получается - значение $height сливается с '$1' и получается строка '$1100px$2'. Как их разделить?

Единственное, что пришло на ум, это написать с пробелом "$1 height$2" - так получается, однако при этом  добавляется лишний пробел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, выход из данной ситуации!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$css = preg_replace('/(div{height:\s?).*(;})/', "\${1}$height\${2}", $css);
```

Тут **\${1}** и **\${2}** — изолированные ссылки.

Comment: Спасибо! Подобного нигде не встречал!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php  
Конец первого абзаца в разделе replacement. :)